# Prestashop 1.6 create admin module

Tags: module, admin, prestashop

Hi i try to create an admin module to prestashop 1.6 but i find some problems.

I would create ( after module installation ) a new tab in main menù and after click on it i would to show a template (.tpl) where the admin user can do some thing on Db.

I have create a folder and insert it in modules folder, in this folder there are this files:

- Controller > admin > AdminGcbulkController.php
- gcbulk.tpl
- gcbulk.php

gcbulk.php:

```
<?php
    if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
        exit;

require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/gcbulk_header.class.php');

class gcbulk extends Module {

private $page_name = '';

public function __construct() {
    $this->name = 'gcbulk'; // il nome del modulo (lo stesso del file principale)
    $this->tab = 'others'; // sezione in cui va inserito
    $this->version = 0.1;
    $this->author = 'Autore';
    $this->need_instance = 0;
    /*
     * need_instance specifica se un istanza del modulo deve essere caricata
     * quando viene visualizzata la lista dei moduli
       (di norma può essere lasciato a 0)   
     */

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('Bulk');
    $this->description = $this->l('Modulo Bulk');

    $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'gcbulk.css', 'all');
    //$this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'js/gc_bulk_script.js');

}

public function install() {

    // Install Tabs
    $parent_tab = new Tab();
    // Need a foreach for the language
    $parent_tab->name[$this->context->language->id] = $this->l('Bulk tab');
    $parent_tab->class_name = 'AdminGcbulk';
    $parent_tab->id_parent = 0; // Home tab
    $parent_tab->module = $this->name;
    $parent_tab->add();

    if (!parent::install()
        || !$this->registerHook('admingc')
    );
}

public function uninstall() {
    // Uninstall Tabs
    $tab = new Tab((int)Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminGcbulk'));
    $tab->delete();

    // Uninstall Module
    if (!parent::uninstall())
        return false;
    return true;
}

public function hookadmingc(){

    $this->smarty->assign(array(
        'ciao' => 'hola'
    ));

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'gcbulk.tpl');
}
}
?>
```

Controller > admin > AdminGcbulkController.php

```
<?php

class AdminGcbulkController extends ModuleAdminController
{

}
```

gcbulk.tpl containe simple html.

The creation of tab work fine but i don't know how to show .tpl after clik on it. Actualy return a blank page on the right of admin contents ( on left there is the menù )

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2):

the controller should implement renderList as following :

```
public function renderList() {
        $return = $this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . '/gcbulk/gcbulk.tpl');             
    return $return;
}
```

I recommend you to move your tpl in this folder : /gcbulk/views/templates/admin/gcbulk.tpl